# Logcat suddenly stops logging crashes

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I was using `adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S` to debug app crashes on the command line for a few hours, when suddenly it stopped outputting logs.

I tried:

- `adb logcat -c` to clean the cache
- Unplugging USB to my phone
- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`
- Plugging USB back in
- `adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S`

Now when the app crashes, it logcat outputs:
`--------- beginning of crash` instead of actual crash logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your app logs were muted. This can happen if your are logging too much too frequently. You can whitelist your app to always capture your logs no matter what. You can do this via adb.

1. First enter the adb shell `adb shell`
2. Get your apps userid `dumpsys package com.your.package.name | grep -i userid` note your userid.
3. Now whitelist the app in logcat `logcat -P 'yourUserId'`